# Plot Dynamic graph of live dataframe of multiple columns using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot dynamic graph with live data.
Below is sample dataframe in which after every 30 seconds I want to add data which I'm collecting from other function.

Dynamic DataFrame

```
    TIME  CE_15750  CE_15800  CE_15850  CE_15900  CE_15950   PE_16000  PE_16050  PE_16100  PE_16150  PE_16200  PE_16250
0  18:54     -5146    -58520    -22849    -78925    -20435     59348     10805      5877       -22      2182     519
1  18:55    -20435    -30990     37085       108     -4634     13528      27239     64451     46905     83803    815
```

I'm trying below code to plot graph but its not giving expected output

```
def draw_method():           

    while True:
        plt.cla()
        temp_var = live_data()
        final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(temp_var)
        final_dataframe.set_index('TIME').plot(figsize = (10,5),grid=True)
        plt.gcf()
        plt.show()
        sleep(30) #30 seconds sleep to add updated data field in dataframe
```

also, how can I give single color for all columns which has **CE_** and single color to **PE_** in graph? The graph I'm getting had different color for each line.

Thanks so much for help

Comment: So about your first question, plt.cla() clears your local axis, so the line should not be exchanging colours at all.  Are you sure that you are having that issue?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Colors is not main concern, I'm not getting live graph of updated values

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And tell me how it went. Is worth noting, my changes were the following. I highly doubt you want to make more than one window be displayed every 30 seconds so i took out plt.show() from you func. And i utilized the FuncAnimation, cause that guy is going to call your dataframe multiple times, and update it for you. Very usefull.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def draw_method():           
    plt.cla()
    temp_var = live_data()
    final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(temp_var)
    final_dataframe.set_index('TIME').plot(figsize = (10,5),grid=True)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), draw_method, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

temp_var = live_data()
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(temp_var)
```

Comment: I tried this code but it's not plotting any graph :(

Comment: Now you see that is probably, because you sir didnt specify in your plot method which graph you want to plot. And since i dont know which one you want to do or how your df looks like i cant help much with that

Comment: @INGI0R1AM0R1 I want to plot line graph, and my df looks exactly looks like Dynamic Dataframe as I mentioned in my question. Am I missing something here?